# fail to implement st_distance_sphere

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, ejs

When trying to create an app that one of its functions is to search for certain places near a given point, I have encountered this error:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: st_distance_sphere (geometry, geometry)
>   function does not exist.

I see in the Doc that it works but I can't see the failure.

```
const distance= Sequelize.fn('ST_Distance_Sphere', Sequelize.col('ubication'), ubication);
```

This is the conflict code

and this is the other variable

```
const ubication = Sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT( ${meeti.ubication.coordinates[0]} ${meeti.ubication.coordinates[1]} )' )`);
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Can you ask your question in english?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function name you are using is obsolete. The proper name is [`ST_DistanceSphere`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html)